# redirect page after completing update or insertion

Tags: php, mysql

There are two pages called `result.php` and `getdata.php`

the `result.php` will show a search results. if search term is not in database then it should redirect to `getdata.php` .

`getdata.php` will analyze query and grab data from other resources then insert / update MySQL database. immeadiate after inserting/updating database then it should redirect to `result.php`

Finally `result.php` will show result as per the query term.

how can be this done with php and mysql??

Answer (score 0):

```
header('location: url');
```

This should help you, just put instead of url something like results.php.

Any issues with redirecting let me know, it could be due to output_buffering being turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PHP docs for [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) and [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).  Below is almost straight from the docs...

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ( $num_rows > 0 ){
    // do something with your SQL result here
} else {
    // redirect to result.php if no rows were found.
    header('location: result.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

actually, I'd put all the code in one php-page, then you wouldn't have to redirect, and easier to maintain.

```
//if no record from search, do the insert now...
code...
//end insert
```

regards,

//t